# How can I extract contours from a raster with Python?

Tags: gdal, shapely, fiona, rasterio, gdal-contour

I currently run [gdal_contour](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html) as a Python subprocess to extract contours from a raster file, but would like to achieve the same function with a combination of [Rasterio](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/), [Shapely](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) and [Fiona](https://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html).

However, once I've used Rasterio to read the raster, I'm not sure how to extract the contours.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where have you looked? A quick search found this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/contours which looks a bit hacky but uses matplotlib's contour drawing code, extracting the coordinates. You are expected to do some basic searching before asking here.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had searched and found [a few](https://github.com/mojodna/marblecutter/issues/54) [ideas](https://github.com/ungarj/mapchete/issues/58) but not that one. Will look in more detail at it, but as you say, it does look a bit hacky. I'm trying to decide whether I should migrate from gdal_contour over to Rasterio, but won't do that unless there is a fairly straightforward approach.

Comment: Rasterio uses a few of GDAL's algorithms (the rasterizer and polygonizer), but not (yet) the contour generator (http://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#aceaf98ad40f159cbfb626988c054c085).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend using **gdal_contour** . The results are likely to be much better than any attempt to re-implement it :-)

Having said that, there should be a way to do this in **rasterio**. I've not tried this, so it may behave differently to how I'd expect it to work in QGIS.

Step 1. **Quantize the raster into contour bands using rasterio**. Use rasterio as a raster calculator. Here's the formula I use for this. This assumes a float raster.  G is the elevation gap between contours. E is the existing elevation value). You might need to tweak this.

```
((int(E+G+1)/G)*G)-G
```

That will 'posterize' a float DEM into multiples of the contour elevation (0, G, 2G, 3G...), should look like this...

[image]

Step 2. **Apply the existing rasterio vectorize example** to the quantized raster. See [this example in github](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/examples/rasterio_polygonize.py).

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use [`measure.find_contours`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.find_contours) from scikit-image.

For example, opening a raster with Rasterio and finding contours from 0 to the highest point:

```
import rasterio
from skimage import measure

with rasterio.open("dem.tif") as dem:
    interval = 5
    max = int(interval * round(np.amax(dem.read(1)) / interval))
    for height in range(0, max, interval):
        contours = measure.find_contours(dem.read(1), height)
            for contour in contours: # find_contours returns "an ndarray of shape (n, 2), consisting of n (row, column) coordinates along the contour"
                # Convert each contour found at this height to LineString or GeoJSON and store elevation as required
```

Note that you'll need to take account of the transform (`dem.transform`) when converting the contours into real-world coordinates and into a `LineString`.