# How could I avoid extracting incorrectly closed contours from a raster with angled sides?

Tags: python, rasterio, gdal-contour, scikit-image

I'm updating a Python script which currently calls [gdal_contour](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html) as a subprocess to extract contours. I'd like to replace `gdal_contour` with [skimage.find_contours](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.8.0/api/skimage.measure.find_contours.html#skimage.measure.find_contours.find_contours).

However the output of the GDAL script differs slightly from scikit-image's output when used on a raster with angled sides. Here are a few images to illustrate:

Before extracting contours, my source raster is first masked (via [rasterio.mask.mask](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html)) with a rectangular polygon, producing something like this:

[image]

When I use `skimage.find_contours`, it produces open contours (which is what I want) when the desired height disappears out of bounds, as in the bottom of the right edge below:

[image]

But when the mask is rotated, like this:

[image]

The contours produced by `skimage.find_contours` now follow the edge of the raster when they pass out of bounds and are closed, as in the bottom-right corner.

(Contours produced by GDAL from the same raster are open in the same corner.)

[image]

I guess I could add a margin, then clip the contours to the correct bounds, but is there another way to deal with this situation?

(I'm open to alternatives to scikit-image, see my [previous question here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268331/how-can-i-extract-contours-from-a-raster-with-python).)

Comment: (I might be off here, but I think) clipping that raster with a rotated mask doesn´t mean the raster extend is clipped. a raster grid has to stay 'unrotated' and all cells outside of the mask and within the new extend (an 'upright' rectangle intersecting the corners of the rotated mask) are asssigned a (default, if not set manually) *no-data* value (maybe even '0'); thus, the contours will follow along the break of actual height values and the inserted *no-data* values, kind of treating it as a steep cliff if you will.

Comment: you can find out if that is the case by trying to select a pixel/grid cell just outside the mask next to that 'cliff': if it returns a value, it´s the automatically created extend. if so, and it happens to actually be '0', you could try to set the *no-data* value to NULL during clipping to get your open contours.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts! Yes, the surrounding pixels are filled with nodata (-9999, but I've tried numpy.NaN). I think what's happening is that `skimage.measure.find_contours` doesn't take nodata into account (only the edge of the array) when deciding whether to open or close a contour. From the [docs](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.find_contours): "contours which intersect the array edge will be left open. All other contours will be closed." I think I might end up extracting the contours for the whole raster, then clipping by the rotated mask.

Comment: okay, I checked the implementation of `find_contours` and it seems it doesn't offer any options. consider sticking to `gdal_contours` since you can specify a *null_value* to take into account. I'm not sure if that means it returns open isohypses, though...